# foreach loop only display last element from array displayed

Tags: php, arrays, loops, concatenation

I have a script that `select` a list of letter from the `array` but the **problem** is it only `display` the last element on the array.

PHP:

```
<?php

$letters = array("A", "B", "C");

foreach($letters as $letter)
{
    $data['#LETTER#'] = $letter;
}

$html = file_get_contents('test.html');

echo $html = str_replace(array_keys($data),array_values($data),$html);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TRY</title>
</head>
<body>
<select>
<option>#LETTER#</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

the output above the script is only `C` which is the last element in the array and I can only select the letter **C** not **A**  **B**   **C**

DESIRED OUTPUT:
`A`
`B`
`C`

why is this happen? can anyone help? I appreciate with explanation. I'm currently new on php.

Comment: You assing every element to the same key in $data. Nemely the key "#LETTER#". On a second note, your method of outputting the array seems rather complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make it like this:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TRY</title>
</head>
<body>
<select>
#LETTER_SELECT#
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
$letters = array("A", "B", "C");
$replace_select = "";
foreach($letters as $letter)
{
    $replace_select .= "<option>".$letter."</option>";
}

$html = file_get_contents("test.html");
echo $html = str_replace("#LETTER_SELECT#",$replace_select);
```

Comment: what do you mean? you want 3 select options but only 1 option, that isn't possible.

Comment: You can't have 3 options into 1 `option` tag, for each `select` element you need another `option` tag.

Comment: Yes, but this will make the `select` tag only display 1 element

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41399/discussion-between-mordalthunder-and-darline)

Answer (score 1):

try to use like. You have single key for all characters, you need to use string concat of php to make a string.

```
foreach($letters as $letter)
{
        $data['#LETTER#'] .= "<option value=$letter>".$letter."</option>";
}

<select>
#LETTER#
</select>
```

Comment: it just output **ABC** in one option it didn't make me selections :(

Comment: concat space " " with it and finally use rtrim to remove last space

Comment: define $data = array(); before foreach loop

Comment: is there no other way to remove `option` tag o the script?

Comment: you can use this script in html between <select></select> tag with echo every line. But there is no way

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $letters = array("A", "B", "C");

    foreach($letters as $letter)
    {
        $data['#LETTER#'] = $letter;
    }

    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
    }

?>
```

Result:
Key: #LETTER#; Value: C

You have only one element in $data array. Try `$data['#LETTER'.$letter.'#'] = $letter;`

Comment: You might want to change your post from just showing the error to only showing a solution. Someone who just copies it will not archive anything here. (as op just did)

Answer (score 0):

i dont actually get what you're trying to do here, but it seems that your loop is always assign values to 1 element of array only, which is #LETTER#.. why not use

```
$data[] = $letter
```

instead and loop it inside the select tag

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the array element in $data with each iteration.

You could implement the PHP within the HTML.

```
<select>

<?php
foreach($letters as $letter)
{
<option> $letter </option>
}
?>

</select>
```